# SwiftUI add subview dynamically but the animation doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swift5

I would like to create a view in SwiftUI that add a subview dynamically and with animation.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isButtonVisible.animation()) {
                Text("add view button")
            }

           if isButtonVisible {
                 AnyView(DetailView())
                      .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                      .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2))
             }else{
                    AnyView(Text("test"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine with the animation . however when i move the view selection part into a function, the animation is not working anymore (since i want to add different views dynamically, therefore, I put the logic in a function.)

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isButtonVisible.animation()) {
                Text("add view button")
            }

            subView().transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                     .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2))   
    }

     func subView() -> some View {
         if isButtonVisible {
             return AnyView(DetailView())
         }else{
            return AnyView(Text("test"))
        }
    }
}
```

it looks totally the same to me, however, i don't understand why they have different result. Could somebody explain me why? and any better solutions?  thanks alot!

Comment: also if you will add your view in ZStack you have to add .zIndex(1) to your animatable view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's your code, modified so that it works:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isButtonVisible.animation()) {
                Text("add view button")
            }

            subView()
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2))
        }
    }

    func subView() -> some View {
        Group {
            if isButtonVisible {
                DetailView()
            } else {
                Text("test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note two things:

1. Your two examples above are different, which is why you get different results. The first applies a transition and animation to a DetailView, then type-erases it with AnyView. The second type-erases a DetailView with AnyView, then applies a transition and animation.
2. Rather that using AnyView and type-erasure, I prefer to encapsulate the conditional logic inside of a `Group` view. Then the type you return is `Group`, which will animate properly.
3. If you wanted different animations on the two possibilities for your subview, you can now apply them directly to `DetailView()` or `Text("test")`.

**Update**

The `Group` method will only work with `if`, `elseif`, and `else` statements. If you want to use a switch, you will have to wrap each branch in `AnyView()`. However, this breaks transitions/animations. Using `switch` *and* setting custom animations is currently not possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You help me a lot. I get another problem. I could not set a switch inside the group. I will get the error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'" 

    func subView() -> some View {
        Group {
            switch status {
            case .start:
               Text("start")
                    break
            case .main:
                Text("main")
                    break
            case .unknown:
                Text("unknown")
                break
            }
        }
 }

Comment: @justicepenny See my update. Basically, you can't, if you want to keep your animations. Use `elseif` statements, and [submit feedback to Apple](http://feedbackassistant.apple.com) if you would like to use `switch` here.

Comment: yea, I have to use if else statement. and the enum has to be with raw value. anyway Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Why does wrapping in AnyView break animations/transitions? Is it because there's no way for it to establish if the view has changed?

Comment: Thank-you! I was getting very frustrated trying to use switch and I didn't have my Views in a Group, so I could not get transitions to work until I found this answer!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it to work with a switch statement by wrapping the function that returns an `AnyView` in a `VStack`. I also had to give the `AnyView` an `.id` so SwiftUI can know when it changes. This is on Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13.3

```
struct EnumView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            view(for: viewModel.viewState)
                .id(viewModel.viewState)
                .transition(.opacity)
        }
    }

    func view(for viewState: ViewModel.ViewState) -> AnyView {
        switch viewState {
        case .loading:
            return AnyView(LoadingStateView(viewModel: self.viewModel))
        case .dataLoaded:
            return AnyView(LoadedStateView(viewModel: self.viewModel))
        case let .error(error):
            return AnyView(ErrorView(error: error, viewModel: viewModel))
        }
    }

}
```

Also for my example in the `ViewModel` I need to wrap the `viewState` changes in a `withAnimation` block

```
withAnimation {
    self.viewState = .loading
}
```

Comment: 2020 Xcode 11, this solution works. Bravo. Id trick is the best. Thank you, @MinnesotaGus.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 14 they added the possibility to use `if let` and `switch` statements in function builders. Maybe it helps for your issues:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/221/whats-new-in-swiftui-for-ios-14 (at the article's bottom)

Comment: I was wondering why the OP was using a function that returns a View instead of another View struct