# SwiftUI custom animated transition in navigationView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

is there a way in SwiftUI to change the standard behaviour of NavigationView/NavigationLink, which is to slide from one view to the next? I'd like to have a custom animation/transition like fade in/out.

I'm trying out things for a while now and solved half of it but struggling with the second half. This code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var appeared: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(appeared)")
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {Text("go to View B")}
            }
            .opacity(appeared)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3.0), value: appeared)
            .onAppear {self.appeared = 1.0}
            .onDisappear {self.appeared = 0.0}
        }
    }
}
```

Works correct when the view appears. It fades in by changing opacity to 1.0 within 3 seconds. All good. But when clicking the `NavigationLink`, to go to View B, it slides away this view and View B (which has the same logic) fades in slowly. I guess this is because `onDisappear` is actually triggered when the view is gone, not when it is about to move away.

Are there any chances to tell SwiftUI to not swipe or slide but do a custom animation/transition?

I'm using Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: For now there is not official way to customise standard `NavigationView` animation, but it is possible to create custom navigation. You might find helpful the approach I provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908741/how-do-i-add-animations-to-transitons-between-custom-navigationitems-made-from-a/59087574?r=SearchResults&s=1|34.4903#59087574). There were requested slide animation there, but actually it can be repacked with any one.

Comment: Hi @Asperi, the approach in your linked post is what I used as a workaround. I created my own NavigationView - very close to the way you provided there.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit late but I just ran into this issue and maybe my solution will help someone else that has this.

I needed to change the opacity, but I couldn't do that with a NavLink, so I did something like this:

```
struct example: View {
    @State var firstView = true
    @State var appeared: Double = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if firstView{
                VStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.firstView = false
                    }){
                        Text("change view")
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                VStack{
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
                .opacity(appeared)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3.0), value: appeared)
                .onAppear {self.appeared = 1.0}
                .onDisappear {self.appeared = 0.0}
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The idea is that when the button is pressed (or whenever whatever calculations you need to do are performed), you can simulate a transition using an if-else{} structure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For me the whole point of using navigation link is to prevent having views like this one. This view, if you want to expand it with a lot of other view will contain way too much information on the app's structure. So even if this is a working compromise it won't help most people who decided to use navigation views.

Answer (score 1):

This is the advertisement of the 3rd party library [NavigationTransitions](https://github.com/davdroman/swiftui-navigation-transitions)

It is easy to use or even enables custom animations;

```swift
NavigationStack {
  // ...
}
.navigationTransition(.slide)
```

It is usage similar to SwiftUI animations, enables combination

```swift
.navigationTransition(
    .slide.combined(with: .fade(.in))
)
```

, and selection with logic;

```swift
.navigationTransition(
    reduceMotion ? .fade(.in).animation(.linear) : .slide(.vertical)
)
```

Custom Example;

```swift
struct Swing: NavigationTransition {
    var body: some NavigationTransition {
        Slide(axis: .horizontal)
        MirrorPush {
            let angle = 70.0
            let offset = 150.0
            OnInsertion {
                ZPosition(1)
                Rotate(.degrees(-angle))
                Offset(x: offset)
                Opacity()
                Scale(0.5)
            }
            OnRemoval {
                Rotate(.degrees(angle))
                Offset(x: -offset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I was relentlessly hoping to find a solution to the no-animation of the insertion on the navigation stack, unfortunately, this great library just replaces the animation, it doesn't add from start.