# NavigationView / NavigationLink custom transition direction

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm attempting to have a `NavigationLink` load a view from the bottom of the screen instead of transitioning from the right, but the "obvious" approach (using a `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))`) doesn't seem to be having any effect.

The below is inside a `NavigationView`:

```
List {
    ForEach(self.message, id: \.self) { message in
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            MessageListCell(....)
        }
    }
}
```

and `MessageListCell`:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(person.firstName).lineLimit(1)
                    .foregroundColor(.main)
            }
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageDetail(otherPerson: otherPerson,
                                                   subject: subject,
                                                   profileHandler: { ProfileReducer($0) })
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom)),
                           tag: 1, selection: $action) {
                NextButton("Proceed")
            }
        }
    }
```

Tapping the `NextButton` consistently transitions from the right side of the screen instead of the bottom. I've tried variations on the above but I'm starting to think that `transition` might not be the right approach.

Comment: For now it is not possible to do this with `NavigationView`, so either wait till next major version of SwiftUI (hoping it will appear there) or create custom navigation stack, thus implementing any transition you like, as for example in topic [How do I add Animations to Transitons between custom NavigationItems made from AnyView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59087574/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi implementing the stack myself does also mean I loose stuff like the swipe back gesture, right?